# post_parent array doesn't work

Tags: query-posts, array, parameter

I have a problem. I created a shortcode to show a *galerie*. I used `query_posts` to fetch all posts of a parent post and get the data from there:

```
function galerie_baureihe() { 
   $parent_id = get_the_id($post->post_parent); $page_id = $parent_id; 
   query_posts(array('post_type' => 'page', 'post_parent' => $page_id, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => ASC,  'posts_per_page' => '9999'));
   if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
         $return_string .= '<div class="dynamische-galerie"><div class="col-4"><div class="dynamische-galerie-wrapper"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, array(285,200) ).'</a><div class="dynamische-galerie-caption"><a href="'.get_permalink().'"><b>'.get_the_title().'</b><br>'.number_format(get_field( 'nettogrundflaeche' ),2,',','.').'<span>&nbsp;m²</span></a></div></div></div></div>';
      endwhile;
   endif;
   wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;
}

add_shortcode( 'galerie_baureihe', 'galerie_baureihe' );
```

This works fine, but now i need such a shortcode on an other side and i need `'post_parent' => array(376, 379),` instead of `'post_parent' => $page_id,`

Here is the other code:

```
function galerie_klassisch_wohnen() { 
   query_posts(array('post_type' => 'page', 'post_parent' => array(376, 379), 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => ASC,  'posts_per_page' => '9999'));
   if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
         $return_string .= '<div class="dynamische-galerie"><div class="col-4"><div class="dynamische-galerie-wrapper"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, array(285,200) ).'</a><div class="dynamische-galerie-caption"><a href="'.get_permalink().'"><b>'.get_the_title().'</b><br>'.number_format(get_field( 'nettogrundflaeche' ),2,',','.').'<span>&nbsp;m²</span></a></div></div></div></div>';
      endwhile;
   endif;
   wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;
}

add_shortcode( 'galerie_klassisch_wohnen', 'galerie_klassisch_wohnen' );
```

But it seems i cant use an array for post_parent. If i use `'post_parent' => 376,` it works but not with `'post_parent' => array(376, 379),`

I hope you guys understand my bad english. What can I do to get the shortcode to work with the array?

Answer (score 4):

It's not recommended to use `query_posts()`, check for example this **warning note** in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts):

> This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As
>   explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter
>   the main query. `query_posts()` is overly simplistic and problematic way
>   to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of
>   the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright
>   fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts
>   pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like
>   making use of `pre_get_posts` hook, for this purpose.

Regarding the post parents array, you're using a wrong parameter. There exists the `post_parent__in` parameter that can handle an array input.

So please try this *secondary* query, instead of your current one:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        'post_type'       => 'page', 
        'post_parent__in' => array(376, 379), 
        'orderby'         => 'title', 
        'order'           => ASC,  
        'posts_per_page'  => 9999
    )
);
```

You should also consider initializing your variable with `$return_string = '';` to avoid the PHP *Undefined variable* notice when you use the `.=` for string concatenation.

Then replace `wp_reset_query()` with `wp_reset_postdata()`, to reset the `$post` variable of the main query.

Comment: Thx for your help.

Comment: @ChristianG. you're welcome, is the problem solved?

Comment: @birgire I have a similar question can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261327/post-parent-using-multiple-id-display-contents